# Searching LinkedHashMap Using nested for loops

Tags: java, search, linkedhashmap

I have a `LinkedHashMap` like so

```
LinkedHashMap <Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> indexToIndecies = new LinkedHashMap <Integer ,ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

I have a method `public int searchGraph(int baseIndex, int searchIndex, int count)`

the point of this search method is; when some one enters `baseIndex`, which is a key, it has to find how many "clicks" it takes to get to the `searchIndex`. the values of the keys are the indexes to which they relate. So a "click" would be going from one key to another. So if my hashmap looks like:

```
0[2]
1[0, 3]
2[0, 5]
3[0, 2, 4, 5]
4[5]
5[2]
6[3, 4, 5]
7[1, 4]
```

to get from 0 to 5 takes two clicks.

so this is the code I have for my method:

```
public int searchGraph(int baseIndex, int searchIndex, int count)
{
    if (baseIndex == searchIndex)
    {

        return count;
    }
    if (searchIndex > indexToIndecies.size()-1){

        return -3;
    }
    else{

        for (int i = 0; i < indexToIndecies.get(baseIndex).size(); i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x< indexToIndecies.get(baseIndex).size(); x++){

                if (indexToIndecies.get(baseIndex).get(x) == searchIndex){

                    return count;
                }
                else{
                    count++;
                }

            }

            baseIndex = (indexToIndecies.get(baseIndex)).get(i);            

        }

        return count;
    }

}
```

Works fine If The `baseIndex` and `seachIndex` I give it has an association, however if it doesn't I am not sure how to catch that... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the HashMap does not contain the specified index, indexToIndecies.get(...) will return null. You will have to check for that.

Comment: this smells like recursion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're not accounting for the possibility that there may be multiple paths from the baseIndex to the searchIndex - presumably you want the shortest path if this is the case.  One way to correct for this is to replace the nested for loops with a single for loop around a recursive call.  Return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if a path isn't found, then if your shortest path has a count of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then you'll know that you weren't able to find a path.  (If you DID find a path with a count of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then something probably went wrong with your path-finding algorithm - you shouldn't have paths that are that long.)  If you want to use nested loops instead of recursion then you can convert the recursive call into a loop by using your own stack variable.

```
public int searchGraph(int baseIndex, int searchIndex, int count) {
    if(baseIndex == searchIndex) {
        return count;
    } else if(count > indexToIndecies.size()) {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE; // cycle in graph
    } else {
        int returnVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i = 0; i < indexToIndecies.get(baseIndex).size(); i++) {
            int temp = searchGraph(indexToIndecies.get(baseIndex).get(i), searchIndex, count + 1);
            returnVal = temp < returnVal ? temp : returnVal;
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

This should return the shortest path, and if it returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then a path wasn't found.

Another option is to return an `Integer` instead of an `int`, in which case you can return a null in the case that you couldn't find a path.

**Edit**: SimonC pointed out in the comments that a cycle in the graph could cause a stack overflow.  I've corrected for this by returning `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if `count` exceeds `indexToIndecies.size()`, since `count` shouldn't exceed the number of keys in the map.

Comment: This could end up causing a stack overflow with a cycle in the graph (assuming the stack size didn't allow `Integer.MAX_VALUE` frames on the stack).

Comment: @SimonC Good point, I've added a guard to terminate the recursion if count exceeds the number of keys in the map

Comment: another option would be to pass a set of visited indecies in the recursive call.  That would provide much faster cycle detection.

Comment: @SimonC That speeds up cycle detection, but slows down the case where there aren't any cycles since you'll be creating a bunch of sets that won't be used.  I'm operating on the assumption that cycles are rare, in which case it's faster to use a guard on `count`; if cycles are common then it would make more sense to use a set of visited values as you suggest.